# Firmware and drivers upgrade for HP Smart Array E200i controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, firmware

What is the recommended way to upgrade firmware and drivers for HP Smart Array E200i controller on HP Proliant BL460c G1?

Is it better to boot from a Maintenance CD or install directly from the OS?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: I gotta have service window next weekend and will give it a shot. It if works, - I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's available to you and how much of a time window you have. If you can afford the downtime, the [HP Firmware Maintenance DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) works very well and can take care of your BIOS, disks, NICs, ILO, etc. You'll probably want to run it via the ILO.

Otherwise, a clean way of running the firmware update is to run the [Windows Server 2003 package](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=3709945&prodSeriesId=1842750&prodNameId=3288156&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-df27c58c24114616bb400d6cdf), which allows you to update the controller firmware from the OS.

[Here are all of the updates and drivers available for your system.](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?cc=us&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=1842750&ac.admitted=1444146108682.125225703.1938120508)

Comment: Worked well! Thx!